# Use Laravel Authentication with pre-existing Single Sign On

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating a web application for a company who use a single sign on for all their current web applications. The single sign on is basically just an API call which either rejects or validates the user and sends back their ID, name, email etc. I am used to using the standard laravel authentication and I'm wondering is there any way I can use it with the single sign on that they us? I would prefer not to have to create the users table if possible.

Comment: Start here: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/socialite

Answer (score 0):

This in in the docs, you change the provider of auth and add your own auth provider.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#adding-custom-user-providers

---

Edit to this question... If you have a large number of users, it may be easier to do it your way, however, it would be a lot easier to just dump the user data and store it in a new database. It may seem faster now, but when you need foreign keys, session storage etc, you will be at a loss later on. It depends on your application, but separating this just because it is easier, actually will be more work than just dumping the users into a new table